# Playing an url in a voice channel in discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot that plays a song in a voice channel. I am using `yt-search` package. It works with no error. My bot connects to the channel and starts playing but it doesn't play anthing at all. There is just silence although i can see that little green circle around the bot's image which shows that it is playing something.

I have installed the new packages. My link is not broken. There isn't any error. But it doesn't play the song.

```
yts( '...search...', function ( err, r ) {
    const videos = r.videos
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection =>{    
        const dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(videos[0].url, {filter: "auidoonly"}));
        receivedMessage.channel.send("Playing:" + " " + videos[0].title);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    console.log(videos[0].url)
})
```

Comment: "auidoonly" should've been "audioonly"